# Error Nullptr was not declared

Tags: c++, cmd

So the nullptr error doesnt show up when i compile it at school and i think i can fix it with adding a line when i compile it, is there another way to get rid of it, and the other two errors i dont understand why im getting them at all. Can someone explain at least the nullptr error?

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

error: 'array' was not declared in this scope

error: 'hours' was not declared in this scope

error: 'nullptr' was not declared in this scope

```
    int main()
{
    float *studentData;
    int numStudents;
    int size;
    int average = getAverage(*array, *hours);
    int median = getMedian(hours);
    int mode = getMode(hours);

    cout << "How many students were surveyed?  ";
    cin >> numStudents;
    studentData = makeArray(numStudents);

     if (studentData == nullptr)
         cout << "Error allocating memory.";
     else
     {
         getFBData(studentData, numStudents);
         selectionSort(studentData, numStudents);

         for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++)
             cout << *(studentData + i) << endl;

         delete[] studentData;
     }

     getAverage(*array, hours);
     printArray(size, hours);
     getMedian(*array, hours);
     getMode(*array, hours);

    cout << "STATISTICS " << endl;
    cout << "\n  Mean: " << average;
    cout << "\n  Median: " << median;
    cout << "\n  Mode: " << mode;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `nullptr` supposed to be declared?

Comment: `nullptr` is a keyword in C++11

Comment: Thats what im confused about, a program we wrote in class the other day used someone almost exactly like this and i didnt get this error, but now when i implement it into my program its all buggered up.

Comment: @MattMcNabb i changed it to NULL instead of nullptr is that the correct decision?

Comment: Yes, `NULL` is a macro that expands to `0`. So that works too (so long as you're including a header that defines `NULL`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On this line:

```
int average = getAverage(*array, *hours);
```

you refer to `array` and `hours`, however you have not declared those things yet. The "school version" of the code must have been different.

Re. the `nullptr` error: that was added to C++ in 2011. Perhaps the school has up-to-date compilers but you have an older compiler at home. If you change `nullptr` to `0` it will be fine.

Comment: That has various versions; try `g++ -v` and compare the output to what you get at school.

Comment: well changing Nullptr to 0, fixed that error but the other two are still there. The only reason i have the lines that are causing the error is to have a variable i can use to cout at the bottom of int main,  could i just call the function again and delete all the trouble some lines?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Your code obviously expects `array` and `hours` to be things.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to change nullptr to 0. Though not all the time this works. But it can be a small code solution.

You can also use -std=c++11 parameter while compiling using g++.
So the compiling command in the terminal will be : 
g++ "your file"  -std=c++11